# how to dereference unique pointers and apply them to std::transform

Tags: c++, c++17, std, unique-ptr

I have a set `std::set<std::unique_ptr<T>, compare> myset{};`, where compare is

```
struct compare {
    auto operator()(std::unique_ptr<T> const& a, std::unique_ptr<T> const& b) const noexcept -> bool
    {
        return a.get() < b.get();
    }
};
```

This (hopefully, but I could be wrong), sorts the unique pointers in the set such that the underlying values are in increasing order (the content of the memory, not the addresses of the pointers). I then have the following code to produce a vector of the values pointed to by the aforementioned unique pointers:

```
auto vec = std::vector<T>();
std::transform(myset.begin(), myset.end(), vec.begin(), [&](std::unique_ptr<T> ptr) -> T {
    return ptr.get();
});
return vec;
```

But this code doesn't work due to an error with the way I have designed the transform apparently - am I 'dereferencing' (getting the values pointed to by the pointers) the unique pointers correctly?

Comment: There is no point in specifying lambda return types explicitly. A compiler will deduce them. With `-> T` you always return a copy, even if returning a reference would've been more efficient.

Comment: `unique_ptr<T>` already has an [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp) which does what you want, you don't need a custom comparison type.

Answer (score 1):

`get` returns a pointer to the managed object. You want `*`. You also need to pass the `std::unique_ptr<T>` by const reference, since `unique_ptr` cannot be copied. Also there are no captures in your lambda function so you can replace `[&]` with `[]`.

Finally when you want to use `std::transform` with an empty vector then you should use `std::back_inserter` to append to that vector. The default is to overwrite existing elements of the vector and since there are none you get undefined behaviour.

Putting all that together you get this

```
std::transform(myset.begin(), myset.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), 
    [](std::unique_ptr<T> const& ptr) -> T {
        return *ptr;
    }
);
```

However `*` will invoke undefined behaviour if there is no managed object in your smart pointer (i.e. if the pointer is null).

You should also be using `*` not `get` in your comparator.